# choosing selection between two static text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Here is my code:

```
 NSString *trimfeedback = [FeedbackTxtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><u>Your 
 answer</u>:<ca>#ya#</ca><br><u>Correct answer</u>:<br>" withString:@"<p>"];
```

the string which is to be replace will be static and 'FeedbackTxtString' can contain text either 'Correct answer' or 'Correct answers' . I need to implement the OR case as i dont know what will be in 'FeedbackTxtString'. If FeedbackTxtString contain 'Correct answers' then string to be replace should be  `<br><u>Your answer</u>:<ca>#ya#</ca><br><u>Correct answers</u>:<br>" withString:@"<p>`, or if it contains 'Correct answer' then string to be replace should be  `<br><u>Your answer</u>:<ca>#ya#</ca><br><u>Correct answer</u>:<br>" withString:@"<p>`
how could i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
  if([FeedbackTxtString rangeOfString:@"Correct answers"].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    NSString *trimfeedback = [FeedbackTxtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><u>Your answer</u>:<ca>#ya#</ca><br><u>Correct answers</u>:<br>" withString:@"<p>"];
  }
  else if([FeedbackTxtString rangeOfString:@"Correct answer"].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    NSString *trimfeedback = [FeedbackTxtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><u>Your answer</u>:<ca>#ya#</ca><br><u>Correct answer</u>:<br>" withString:@"<p>"];
  }
```

Comment: i am doing that already but every time flow goes to if {} - statment

Comment: now check answer after editing check every time FeedbackTxtString might have Correct answers only